# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'noHide' of undefined

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, shiny-server

I am running a shiny app using leaflet package 
when running locally it works fine when I upload to the server i get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'noHide' of undefined
```

This is the code of java script that it refers to:

```
if (label !== null) {
            if (labelOptions !== null) {
              if(Leaflet(labelOptions.noHide)) {
                marker.bindLabel(label, labelOptions).showLabel();
              } else {
                marker.bindLabel(label, labelOptions);
              }
            } else {
              marker.bindLabel(label);
            }
          }
```

The code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/eliavs/scrath)

Comment: You should post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of trying to get people to go to some external site.

Comment: @ray yes you are right, but because it is a big file and i don't know exactly where the problem is i did both, I also posted the script where i get the error and also a link to the whole code